# Perl Remove invalid characters, invalid latin1 characters from string

Tags: mysql, perl, encoding, character-encoding

I have a perl script that reads from a web service and saves in a mysql table. this table uses latin1. from the web service there are coming some wrong characters and need to remove them before saving them in the database, otherwise they get saved as '**?**'

wanted to do something similar as: 
    **$desc=~s///gsi;**

but is not removing them.

the webservice that has the wrong characters is: **https://jobvacancies.services.businesslink.gov.uk:8443/vacancy/26653478**

using a user agent to get the data, seems coming in utf8 but the characters need to be removed:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new ();

$ua->default_headers->push_header ('Accept' => 
                   "text/html,application/xhtml" .
                   "+xml,application/xml");
$ua->default_headers->push_header ('Accept-Charset' => "utf-8");

my $doc = $ua->get ("https://jobvacancies.services.businesslink.gov.uk:8443/vacancy/26653478")
```

Comment: Is your program really able to handle both HTML and XML? If not, you should fix the Accept header to tell the server exactly what you want.

Comment: yes can accept both

Comment: Your code extract does not show how the XML is parsed. Do you use an XML parser?

Comment: yes: my $jobXml = XML::LibXML::Reader->new (string => $doc->content) or die "error reading xml";

Comment: Seems like the better course of action would be to fix the table, or maybe convert the unicode characters to HTML entities (yes, that's a really bad idea, too, but far more correct than just casually throwing away characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the characters outside the 7-bit ascii set (which are sufficient to display messages in english), you can you do this:

```
$desc=~s/[^\x00-\x7f]//g
```

**Edit**: If you want something more elaborate that supports the entire `latin-1` set, you can do this:

```
use Encode;

$desc=encode('latin-1',$desc,sub {''});
```

This will remove exactly the characters that cannot be represented by `latin-1`. Note that this line expects that the `utf-8` flag is on for the string `$desc` and that the resulting string will have the `utf-8` flag is off.

Finally, if you want to preserve the euro sign (€), please note that you cannot do that with `latin-1` because it is not part of that encoding. You will have to use a different encoding, such as `ISO-8859-15`.

Comment: This will also encode character in the upper part of the Latin-1 character set.

Comment: ASCII is inadequate for English text—it really is. Don’t try it. With such a naïve approach, you will loose €.

Comment: correct. euro is excluded from the regex. maybe can do some preprocessing before for the euro,pound and other symbols: $desc=~ s/€/&#8364;/sgi;

Comment: thanks, is the best solution for removing non latin-1 chars. only problem with this solution is it removes the visible charcter '...' which comes after the signature part. this character is not latin1 but seems to be stored well in latin1 mysql table. with dolmen's answer was able to show the text exactly as is coming including the control characters([]) stored as their html entity code "&#61482;&#61472;&#61472;" instead of "?". only problem with that sprintf approach is the euro is not translated properly  to its html entity code, but if doing a replace before then works fine.

Comment: best option is to replace control characters (white square) that translate into '?' , and keep other utf8 chars that store well in latin1

Comment: You can do `$desc=~s/…/.../g` to convert the ellipsis character to 3 dots.

Answer (score 0):

The content sent by the web service is XML that contains HTML in the `Description` tag. If this is that content that worries you, another option than deleting non-Latin-1 character is to encode characters using HTML encoding:

```
$desc =~ s/([^\x00-\x7f])/sprintf("&%d;", ord $1)/ge
```

Here is an example:

```
$ echo 'é' | perl -C -pE 's/([^\x00-\x7f])/sprintf("&%d;", ord $1)/ge'
&233;
```

Comment: yes only problem why seems better to remove them is in this doc there are two utf8 characters: one is displayed as a square[] and needs removed (seems originally was a bullet point from the context) and the other one is inside the signature which comes displays as a valid character '…' however both are valid utf8 characters

Comment: wouldnt it need the '#' : sprintf("&#%d;", ord $1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your column definition to `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` so that the naughty character does not need to be removed, and can actually be stored.

Comment: got restrictions with this, is a generic schema used for many clients (key,value) and prefer to keep latin1 even if chars are replaced by another representation

Comment: latin1 characters can be converted to UTF-8, but not vice versa.  The connection parameters allow for that conversion, but it requires that the column(s) be converted to utf8mb4.